# Does gitignore work for files that have previously been versioned?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file in my branch that I would like ignored.  I added it to `.gitignore` but, when I change it, it still shows under deltas in `git status`.  gitignore does work for previously not versioned files.

Is the reason gitignore doesn't work in this instance the fact that the file in question has already been versioned?  How do I circumvent this and ignore it on a going forward basis?

Comment: @janamargaret if the file is already tracked, then the gitignore will have no bearing on it. The file needs to first become untracked

Comment: @janamargaret no you don't need to commit `.gitignore`, it takes effect when it exists, committed or not. That being said, it's a recommended practice to add `.gitignore` to version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is not working because the file is already being tracked by Git.

An approach would be to first delete the file and commit.

Then re-add the file (along with the entry to .gitignore) and commit again.

Another potential approach: [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 3):

The files which have already been added to version control are not ignored even if they are under `.gitignore`

To start ignoring these files, they should first be removed from version control. They can be removed using `git rm --cached <file>` command. The `--cached` option removes files from version control while preserving them on disk. Now, the `<file>` should stop appearing in list of updated files.